# 1:1 variant on m:m Eloquent Relationship in Laravel 5.5: Is the example valid?

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I am trying to specify a 1:1 relationship, via orgperson(), despite the m:m nature of an existing relationship, orgs(), so that I can eager load 1 default organization.

I have the following objects, each with a table:

- person model - important note, defaultOrgID exists on person
- organization record
- pivot connecting both (orgperson) with additional fields

Is my "jerry-rigging," as shown in the orgperson() function, valid?

If not, is there anything close that would be?

In the Person model, the relevant relationships are as follows:

```
    // many-to-many relationship from person to orgs via org-person table
    public function orgs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Org::class, 'org-person', 'personID', 'orgID');
    }

    // "pivot table" with additional fields
    public function orgperson()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrgPerson::class, 'personID', 'personID')
            ->where([
                ['orgID', $this->defaultOrgID],
                ['personID', $this->personID]
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: why not use withPivot instead of declaring a new relationship ?

Comment: As I understand withPivot, and in my attempt to try it, I'm still getting a relationship collection because it's build on the m:m via the belongsToMany eloquent function.  I'm trying to get a 1:1 "relationship" for the specific orgperson record in question.  I'm willing to accept that my goal, as designed, may  not be possible but was hoping for a few other folks to look at and comment on the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was as simple as I had hoped.

My intermediate table (org-person) had been defined as a Model.  I toyed with having its class extend Pivot instead of Model but, in the end, I stuck with Model.

The code that works (relationship on my Person model):

```
public function orgperson()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrgPerson::class, 'personID', 'personID')
        ->where('orgID', $this->defaultOrgID);
}
```

This gets me the desired result of being able to have this relation return a single entry from what could be multiple records in the pivot table based on the value in defaultOrgID.

My problem was using "belongsTo" instead of "hasOne."

Answer (score 0):

Since you already define your relationship 'orgs' better approach would be:

```
public function orgperson()
    {
        return $this->orgs()
            ->where("orgID", '=', $this->defaultOrgID)
            ->where("personID", '=', $this->personID);       

    }
```

Comment: Can this be lumped into a query and eager loaded?  I know I can get the data I want using something like this but in other areas of the application, I want to get event objects that have registered "persons."  And I want to be able to eager load all of the bits of data all at once.  I'm going to try this now to see about answering my own question in this comment.

Comment: After fixing the aove--changing the ambiguous orgID to org-person.orgID--the above does not achieve what I'm hoping to get -- eager loaded relationship data for the proper "orgperson" value.  The output shows a null orgperson relation.  It stays null even after doing a person->load('orgperson') which has been showing the data in other versions.

Comment: Turns out that this couldn't have worked because it's taking information from Orgs, not OrgPerson (which is the intermediate (or pivot) table for which I also have a model.